# How to get column values from one sheet to another?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two sheets in excel both having common value of Loan Id and i have one extra column in first sheet "Assignee name". I need the same assignee name value for all row by referring Loan id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vlookup` for this

```
`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)`
```

Where Sheet1 has both loanId and Assignee name. Loan IDs in column A and Assignee name in Column B

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response could you please share example for this, and i need to write this formula for formula isn't ?

Comment: updated the answer with sample data. This is a simple vlookup case. You can check excel formulas also for further guidance.Please provide your data,so that i can guide you further